# How to pass multiple values in one parameter to SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to pass a parameter to stored procedure but with multiple values and place it in Where condition as IN (Values)

My SP:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPoliciesPageWise]
    (
       @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT 
    )
AS

BEGIN

      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (ORDER BY [ID] ASC)AS RowNumber
     ,[ID]  
     ,[PolicyNumber]
     ,[FileName]
     ,[FileBarcode]
     ,[BoxBarcode]
     ,[CityID]
     ,[DocTypeID]
     ,[ProdcutType]
     ,[CategoryID]
     ,[TotalImages]
     ,[PIN]
     ,[PolicyHolder]
     ,[IDNo]
     ,[BranchID]
     ,[IntroducerID]
     ,[IssueDate]
     ,[FilePath] 
     ,[BranchName]
     ,[DocType]
 INTO #Results
  FROM dbo.Polices
  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) 
  FROM #Results
  SELECT * FROM #Results

  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) +     @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results

END
```

What i need is to pass multiple policies and filter the result based on that.
also i need this parameter as defualt if it is empty i need to select without insert it in the Where condtion
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: So you want to generate a IN list, basically?  You'll need to pass in a delimited list, then split it and build the in list inside your proc.

Comment: use Table valued parameters? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Andrew dear i did this in my application code it is ready to be sent to SP in delimited list.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: @MMomani stop thinking about a delimited list. In your application code, create a DataTable. Then pass a *set*, not a comma-delimited string, to your stored procedure using a table-valued parameter.

Comment: Andrew how i can implemnt this in my SP, just pass the delimited param and place it in the Where condition like this WHERE PolicyNumber IN (@delimitedList) ?

Comment: Aaron why dear? it is already ready in my code i can simply pass it here without doing this step in SQL as i am not professional in it really

Comment: There are a ton of approaches, if you'll google for SQL Server split function. Having said that, Aaron and Eric are correct, table-valued parameters really are the way to go.

Comment: okay dears thank you, but i still not understand why i must use split i don't need to split the delimited list as i know IN working like this IN ('1234','5678','9876') and this i already bulit it in my application and ready to send it as is to the SP

Comment: Sure, if you're really that determined to use the existing delimited list without splitting, you could do that using dynamic sql inside your stored procedure -- building a string variable that contains your query, then executing that string variable using the `EXECUTE` command -- but that's complicated too.  Splitting is the probably the same or less trouble.  Passing a table parameter may run more efficiently, and be easier to understand... the only drawback of a table is that it would involve changes to your *calling* code, as well as the stored procedure.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but passing table param to SP requires user defined data type. Otherwise I agree with solution to pass list as a table.